# How can I see what xcm message the moonbeam/river parachain has sent?

Tags: xcm, moonbeam, moonriver, cross-chain-explorers

I sought to find xcm extrinsics sent from the moonriver/moonbeam parachains but it seems to do things a little differently. Where can I find the sent message or at least the message hash so that I can correlate it with the UMP message id that I can see on the relay chain?

Are the messages inside the `ethereum.Executed` extrinsic? Would decoding the `eth.Log` events show some of this? Is there a good moonscan link that can show some of this decoded?

With kind regards,

Giles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the ump queue does not show an event with the message hash. We aim at solving that in this PR: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/1228. Right now there is no clear way to correlate for any chain using the xtokens or the pallet-xcm pallets, since non of them (except for the ***send*** extrinsic in pallet-xcm), since none of them (at least that I know of) deposit an event with the message nor the messageId

Comment: Excellent news. Much appreciated that you're making it easier for cross-chain explorers to show what's going on.